# I have a nested array which consists of elements from another array grouped into 2 . After that, I want to display an attribute of each element

Tags: c++

I've created a nested array(female_double_entry) consisting of elements from another array(arr_female_double) grouped into 2. I am trying to display "city" attribute of all the elements of the nested array, but I can't, I get an error saying "no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}’ and ‘Player’)" Perhaps I'm doing something wrong in other parts of my code. the code below is only a small part of the entire code. "Player" is a structure that I have previously defined having an attribute of "city". I'm sorry if I'm not making any sense, if so, please ignore this question.

```
std::vector<std::vector<Player> > female_double_entry(8, vector<Player>(2));

std::cout << "female_double_entry.size = "<< female_double_entry.size() << '\n';

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) { //there are 8 entries for female double players
    for (int j = 0; i < 1; j++) {
        female_double_entry[i][j] = arr_female_double[2*i];
        female_double_entry[i][j] = arr_female_double[2*i+1];
    }
}

std::cout << "female_double_entry array size: "<<female_double_entry.size()<< '\n';

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        std::cout<<female_double_entry[i][j].city;
    }
}
```

Comment: What line is this happening on? Is it in this code? The only culprit could be std::cout<<female_double_entry[i][j].city, that I can see. What data type is city?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I believe that line is the cause of the error. Sorry, I forgot to state the data type of city... It's string. I'm going to sleep now. Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if it's operator order of precedence. Without looking, the << operator might be getting evaluated before the . operator. Maybe try adding parenthesis around the entire female_double_entry[i][j].city and see if the problem disappears.

Comment: Thank you for your piece of advice. Perhaps there's something wrong in other parts of my code. It's alright, I'll try to take another approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my question. Firstly, the second line in the first nested loops should be:
female_double_entry[i][j+i] = arr_female_double[2*i+1];
and not:
female_double_entry[i][j] = arr_female_double[2*i+1];

Secondly, when I changed the array declaration to the ordinary array:
Player female_double_entry[8][2];
I could display the city. I don't know though, why the vector approach didn't work.